# Google Cloud -- Ask a bucket owner to grant you 'storage.objects.list' permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

I am new to google cloud. I would like to use the output from the bucket in google cloud for my research. However, the error message shows that:

Additional permissions are required to list objects in this bucket. Ask a bucket owner to grant you 'storage.objects.list' permission.

I am not sure how to ask the bucket owner. Could someone help? Thanks!

Comment: so you know the bucket name but you don't own it and you want the owner of the bucket to grant you read-only access to the bucket. Well, do you know the owner of the bucket? If so, just ask them.

Comment: 1) Provide the bucket owner with three pieces of information: a) Your Google Cloud IAM identity (email@gmail.com or email@myorg.com); b) The bucket name; c) Request the permission **storage.objects.list** added to your identity. 2) If you plan to read objects in the bucket you will need more permissions. 3) If you do not know the bucket owner, we cannot help you find out who owns/manages the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what type of access is planned to grant by the bucket owner but if you only want to list the objects in a bucket, it's recommended to set a [custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) only with this permission "storage.objects.list" to your user account, also the Storage Object Viewer role let you list the objects in a bucket using [predefined roles](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles)